# How to determine the IP ranges used by the GCP load balancers

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

## How to determine the IP ranges used by the GCP load balancers

I am operating several VM instances on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). They are behind an HTTP(S) load balancer.

In order to restrict the access based on the origin IP address, I configured the Nginx on each VM instance as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.example.com;

  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
  real_ip_recursive on;
  set_real_ip_from 130.211.0.0/22; # GCP load balancers
  set_real_ip_from 35.191.0.0/16;  # GCP load balancers

  ...
}
```

I found the IP ranges `130.211.0.0/22` and `35.191.0.0/16` on the [Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#firewall_rules) section of "HTTP(S) Load Balancing Concepts" document page.

But, in the actual operation, I noticed that accesses could come from another IP range `35.190.0.0/17`.

So, I consulted a [section](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#where_can_i_find_product_name_short_ip_ranges) of the Google Compute Engine FAQ and I learned that I can get the list of *all* public IP ranges of GCP.

This list is very long and seems to include the IP ranges that are *not* used by the load balancers.

I have two questions:

1. How can I determine the IP ranges used by the GCP load balancers?
2. How can I update the Nginx configuration when the IP ranges change?

Comment: Just a small clarification, the ranges listed in the LB firewall section are the IP ranges that the actual Load Balancers have, not the IPs you assign to your Load Balancer Front end. The IPs you assign to your front end can be any external Google IP address. External IPs from this group can be assigned to VMs, Load Balancer Front Ends or any other resource that requires an external IP

Comment: Patrick, do you mean that we cannot know whether an HTTP request comes to the backend through any GCP load balancer or not?

Comment: yes you can, requests will come from 4 different ranges listed in the Load Balancer firewall section. But those IP ranges are not the same as the ones you assign as the external IP to your LB front end. the 35.19.0.0/17 is part of Google's external IP ranges, but it is not reserved for any specific use

Comment: Patric, which page do you refer by the Load Balancer firewall section? I see only two ranges on https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#firewall_rules.

Comment: So the documentation isn't great, only the two you mentioned are actually documented properly. There are two other ranges used that you will notice when running kubernetes ingress resources: 209.85.204.0/22 and 209.85.152.0/22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this exact same issue while testing a deployment on Google Kubernetes Engine. I found out that if you assign a static IP address to your load balancer, that is the additional IP address that traffic will be forwarded from. Static IP addresses are always out of the listed range for Google's load balancers since they can be reserved for purposes other than load balancing. In my case I whitelisted the range that Google listed along with my static IP and everything is working fine; traffic doesn't get forwarded from any other IP addresses.

Whitelisting the entire range of Google's IP addresses might open a security hole where someone will be able to spoof their IP on your site. If someone uses a Google Compute Engine instance that is assigned one of Google's IPs that you whitelisted, they will be able to spoof their IP by changing the forwarded-for headers.

Answer (score 4):

Its not that long, I would just put them all in a separate file and include that in your Nginx config.

Then just run a bash script as a cron job to create a new config file, compare it with the current one and restart Nginx if necessary.

Something like this should get you started:

```
for i in $(host -t txt _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com | egrep -o "_cloud-netblocks[0-9]+\.googleusercontent.com"); do
host -t txt "$i" | egrep -o "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/[0-9]+" | sed -e 's/^/set_real_ip_from /' -e 's/$/;/' >> newhostsfile;
done;
diff -N newhostsfile hostsfile > /dev/null && rm newhostsfile || mv newhostsfile hostsfile | nginx -s reload;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the word "long" because I suppose that the list includes IP addresses of ordinary VM instances. If my guest is correct, these addresses should be excluded. I want to know how to determine the role of each IP address in the list.

Comment: I ran my code, there are 54 entries in the list. If you want to know exactly what Google does from every ip address in use on GCP then yeah, good luck with that. 